# Toast Message After 5 sec in Android

Tags: android

I want To know how can I Toast The Message or String after 5 seconds In Android..? Suggest Some Solutions or Code..

```
Toast.makeText(Getapplicationcontext,"Hello", Toast.length_Short);
```

I have Simple code can anybody have idea..?

Comment: Add a postDelayed Handler of 5000 milliseconds

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you want to show Toast after 5 seconds when your activity is open, you have to use `Handler class` for that checkout below code -

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}, 5000);
```

where 5000 is time in milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

    // Add the line which you want to run after 5 sec.

    }
},5000);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: It will not work from Android 8 to Android 10

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Handler` class like this   :

```
Handler h= new Handler();
h.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();\\your code
},5000);\\miliseconds
```